# How can one group character values into a new value and make a new column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a large number of categorical values 1-106 in a column called chairs. I would like to group them into zones, for example 1-10 would be in zone 1. And putting all these zones in a new column based on the original value. I have been attempting to do this with dplyr but failing miserably. I'm sure there is a simple solution I'm missing, so I will send it out to people more knowledgeable than myself. 
thus far I've tried I tried :

```
grouptest <- date_data
oldvals <-c(c("1", "2"), c("3":"26"), c("43":"58"), c("27":"35"), c("36":"40"), c("59":"66"), 
          c("79":"88"), c("67":"78"), c("89":"100"), c("101":"102"),  c("103":"106"))
newvals <-factor(c("1", "2", "3","4","5","6", "7", "8","9","10","11"))
grouptest$zone <- newvals[match(grouptest$seating, oldvals)]
grouptest
```

but the zone columns does not make any sense at all. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your values in the chair column are actually integers (1:106), you can use `cut` to divide them up into intervals. Otherwise you can use `cut` on the levels of the factor variable.

Comment: I think that you may have wanted `newvals <- factor(floor(as.numeric(oldvals)/10))`